# Azure Function + Python - Output compressed zipfile

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I am trying to output files to my storage blob from my Azure Function running python code. I have accomplished returning files without any compression using the following code:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('Data_out.zip', 'w') as myzip:
    myzip.write('somefile.js')
print 'adding somefile.js'
```

and

```
RFile = open('Data_out.zip', 'r').read()
output = open(os.environ['returnfile'], 'w')
output.write(RFile)
```

However, as soon as I start using any form of compression and read this back into the output binding the file copied to my storage blob ends up being corrupt and unreadable.

```
import zipfile

try:
    import zlib

    compression = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
except:
    compression = zipfile.ZIP_STORED

modes = {zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED: 'deflated',
         zipfile.ZIP_STORED: 'stored',
         }

print 'creating archive'
zf = zipfile.ZipFile('Data_out.zip', mode='w')
try:
    print 'adding log.txt and outputfile with compression mode', modes[compression]
    zf.write('log.txt', compress_type=compression)
    zf.write('somefile.js', compress_type=compression)
finally:
    print 'closing'
    zf.close()
```

and

```
RFile = open('Data_out.zip', 'r').read()
output = open(os.environ['returnfile'], 'w')
output.write(RFile)
```

Now this produces a fully functional zip-file on my webjobs folder. But I am unable to copy this correctly to my storage blob. My guess is that using the .read() alongside .write() does not make much sense when handling a compressed file. But at the moment I am stuck not knowing what to do next.

I am using Python 2.7.

Any Suggestions?

**EDIT**
A further clarification of the exact error I am experiencing:

When using

```
RFile = open('Data_out.zip', 'r').read()
output = open(os.environ['returnfile'], 'w')
output.write(RFile)
```

I am able to finish the function script, but the zip file that appears in my Azure storage blob is only a few bytes in size and it is corrupt. The zip file still on my webjobs storage is in fact approx 250kb, and I am able to extract the files back to my webstorage from it.

So the source of my error is most likely in my output code:

```
RFile = open('Data_out.zip', 'r').read()
output = open(os.environ['returnfile'], 'w')
output.write(RFile)
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error you're seeing?

Comment: Sure. I have included a more detailed description of the error I am experiencing in the main text. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some more testing I found a solution to my problem. I turned to the python SDK for azure-storage. This provided me with more control.

I used KUDU to install the azure-storage package (had to upgrade PIP for it to properly install) and I imported the package into my script with the additional reference to the "/env/Lib/site-packages" like so:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..', 'env/Lib/site-packages')))
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
```

My output method is then the same as explained in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage .

The code ended up like this:

```
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='myaccount', account_key='mykey')
block_blob_service.create_container(username)
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(
    username,
    returnfile,
    'Data_out.zip')
```

and that was it!

Comment: This copies the file as in zip to the destination, does not extract the zip . Is there some parameters missing that has to be included?

Comment: @Sundar N. Then it works as intended. The intention was simply to copy the zipfile to the azure storage blob.